# Avoid emptying dictionary recursively

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion

I am trying to create a dictionary from a list recursively and my code only works when there is only one item in the list. It fails for multiple items and I suspect that this is because the dictionary is being recreated through each instance of the recursion instead of adding to it after the first instance. How can I avoid doing this so that the whole list is converted to a dictionary?

Note: the list is a list of tuples containing two items.

```
def poncePlanner(restaurantChoices):
    if len(restaurantChoices) == 0:
        return {}
    else:
        name, resto = restaurantChoices[0][0], restaurantChoices[0][1]
        try:
            dic[name] = resto
            poncePlanner(restaurantChoices[1:])
            return dic
        except:
            dic = {name: resto}
            poncePlanner(restaurantChoices[1:])
            return dic
```

Intended input and output:

```
>>> restaurantChoice = [("Paige", "Dancing Goats"), ("Fareeda", "Botiwala"),
                  ("Ramya", "Minero"), ("Jane", "Pancake Social")]
>>> poncePlanner(restaurantChoice)
{'Jane': 'Pancake Social',
 'Ramya': 'Minero',
 'Fareeda': 'Botiwala',
 'Paige': 'Dancing Goats'}
```

Comment: The `dict` statement already creates a dictionary for you if a list contains `(key, value)` tuples. For example: `dict([('one', 1), ('two', 2)])` creates a dict: `{'one': 1, 'two': 2}`. Are you sure you want to write this function yourself?

Comment: Yes, I am doing it as a coding challenge and need to figure it out. I know dict easily does this but the challenge here is to find a way to do it recursively & without loops.

Comment: Can you please provide example(s) of the inputs and the expected output?

Comment: Are you trying to transform `restaurantChoices = [[name1, resto1], ..., [name_i, resto_i]]` into `{name1: resto1, ..., name_i: resto_i}`?

Comment: That is exactly it. I have figured out a way to do it though, but feel free to add to it since there are different ways to do it!

Answer (score 1):

You have the edge condition, so you need to define what to do when you have more than one. Here you just take the first tuple, make a dict, and then add the results of recursion into that dict:

```
restaurantChoice = [("Paige", "Dancing Goats"), ("Fareeda", "Botiwala"),
                    ("Ramya", "Minero"), ("Jane", "Pancake Social")]

def poncePlanner(restaurantChoice):
    if not restaurantChoice:
        return {}
    head, *rest = restaurantChoice
    return {head[0]: head[1], **poncePlanner(rest)}

poncePlanner(restaurantChoice)
```

Returning:

```
{'Jane': 'Pancake Social',
 'Ramya': 'Minero',
 'Fareeda': 'Botiwala',
 'Paige': 'Dancing Goats'}
```

Comment: Do `head, *rest = restaurantChoice` and `**poncePlanner(rest)` have `O(n)` or `O(1)` time complexity?

Comment: Yes, you are allocating new lists and dicts when you do this. Generally for school assignments that involve both python and recursion, you don't really care about that. The idea is to understand recursive behavior, if you want an efficient solution, recursion is usually the wrong approach in python.

Comment: I see, thanks. I was curious to know for my general knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

Since `restaurantChoices` are already `(key,value)` pairs, you can simply use the built-in function `dict` to create the dictionary:

```
def poncePlanner(restaurantChoices):
    return dict(restaurantChoices)
```

Without built-in functions, you can also use a simple `for-loop` to return the desired transformation:

```
def poncePlanner(restaurantChoices):
    result = {}
    for key,value in restaurantChoices:
            result[key] = value
    return result
```

---

If you really want recursion, I would do something like this, but it doesn't make sense because the lists are not nested:

```
def poncePlanner(restaurantChoices):
    def recursion(i, result):
        if i<len(restaurantChoices):
            key, value  = restaurantChoices[i]
            result[key] = value
            recursion(i+1, result)
        return result
    return recursion(0,{})
```

This recursive function has `O(1)` time/space complexity per call, so it runs with optimal efficiency.

The main problem with the original code is that the dictionary `dic` is not passed to the deeper recursion calls, so the new contents are never added to the final dictionary. (They contents added to new dictionaries and forgotten).

Comment: Not the downvote, but it's probably warranted. Your first code returns a ValueError with the original input.

Comment: What Python version are you using? I don't get value errors.

Comment: I'm using 3.8.5 at the moment. `zip(*restaurantChoice)` will give you `[('Paige', 'Fareeda', 'Ramya', 'Jane'), ('Dancing Goats', 'Botiwala', 'Minero', 'Pancake Social')]` which results in the expected error `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required` Seems like the easier choice is just `dict(restaurantChoice)` if you're going to ignore the OPs requirement of a recursive solution.

Comment: Sorry, `restaurantChoices` are already `(key, value)` pairs, you can simple use `dict(restaurantChoices)` to solve the entire problem.

Comment: All three approaches work correctly including the recursion as requested. Also some useful comments provided. So UPVoted as useful.